# Using Google Cloud Print to print to a designated printer in a restaurant from an app

Tags: android, ios, node.js, printing, google-cloud-print

The restaurant I'm working with has a pos printer in their brick and mortar building. So when a user makes a purchase on the app, we're using square as a payment processor, I'd like to use google cloud print to send a job to that printer in the restaurant itself. Using google cloud print though you seem to need the user using the app to sign in to google first and that wouldn't make any sense in the flow of the app because it's  not a user printer we're sending a job to. I'm using node.js and parse-server on the backend and this will be implemented in iOS and Android apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow is as follows:

1. Your client need to have a Google Account (gmail)
2. Your client need to add the printer in to their Google Account. If the printer supports by default this option, then they have to follow the instruction included on the printer. If the printer doesn't support Google Print then their have to install Chrome on the computer that the printer is connected, add the printer to the system, and add the printer to Google Print. They can follow this [instruction](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1069693?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).
3. Once they have the printer added to their account they can decide who can have access to their printers.

How to gain access to the client printer

1. In your app that you are building for them, you have to have a button that allows them to grant access to their printers to your app using [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).
2. Once they grant access to your app, you will be able to manage their printers on their behalf.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining the flow for me! I don't think google cloud print is what I want to use for this job though. Is there anything you could suggest for what I need done? I'd like something that requires no user interaction as they don't need to be involved with the printing process.

Comment: Well if you have a web based app this is your best option, if your app is a desktop one, then you can use the printer connected to the computer directly. If the app is a mobile one, then you might give your client a network printer, so you can just add the printer to the mobile system, but for that you need a printer that supports Android and iOS.

Comment: I have an ios/android app with a webview. It's weird there's not a way to do this. I don't want the user involved with printing the tickets that go to the food makers.

Comment: Then the client need a bluetooth printer like [this](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/bluetooth-receipt-printer) so you can print form the mobile app directly to the tiny printer.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to print from the device in the restaurant after a push notification is received from that same device after users order?

Comment: What do you mean by device? The mobile app that takes the order, or another server somewhere else? I mean this is getting bit crazy :) Basically if you have access to a computer that has a printer attached to it, you can print directly to it. just make a desktop app that will get the data and print stuff out, you can do it in NodeJS if you want.

Comment: They use an ipad to handle orders, I was thinking that if the ipad in the restaurant got a push notification after every order it could send a job to the printer in the rest.

Comment: If the use that then sure a mini bluetooth printer in their pockets will do the trick. Normally those printers come with ready to use SDK, and printing to them should is easy.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Sorry this conversation was long. This is experimental for me and I'm trying to work out what's best for all involved. You've helped me a ton. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, glad to help :) ping me on Twitter if you get more questions :)